# PHP simple html dom - can't traverse unhelpful markup

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using simple_html_dom to try and get a title and (possibly multiple) times from a table that looks something like this:

```
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="title">Some title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="time">11:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr> 
    <td class="title">Another title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="time">16:00 22:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="time">21:00</td>
    </tr>
    // And so on
```

My simple_html_dom is currently setup like this:

```
foreach($html->find('tr') as $film) {

   $title = $film->find('td.title',0)->plaintext;
   $time = $film->find('td.time',0)->plaintext;

   if ($time) { 

     $showtimes .= ' '.$time;
   }

  if ($title) { 

    echo $title

    if (!empty($showtimes)) {

      echo $showtimes;          
    }   
 }
```

A title might have duplications (which is ok) and there might be multiple times for any individual title.

To make a long story short, I can sort of get there, but it's messy and I'm not ending up with a tidy list of titles with associated time(s) that can be used in an easy way - i.e. dump it all into a database.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to iterate over all the `td.title`s. For each of those, the `td.time`s will always be in the following `tr`, so:

```
foreach($html->find('td.title') as $td) {
  $title = $td->text();
  $times = array();
  while(($tr = $td->parent->next_sibling()) && ($td = $tr->find('td.time', 0))){
    $times[] = $td->text();
  }
  var_dump($title, $times);
}
```

Comment: Enissay - Thanks for getting me started!

Answer (score 0):

What an aweful HTML code indeed :>

Try:

```
foreach($html->find('tr td') as $row) {

    if ($row->class == 'title') {
        echo "<br>".$row->plaintext;
    }
    elseif ($row->class == 'time') {
        echo "\t".$row->plaintext;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Some title  11:00
Another title   16:00   21:00
```

You can also use a flag that changes when `class="title"` is found

I hope this gives you some ideas :)

Comment: Super - thanks for the input! I also just realised that the main problem was knowing when I was I had reached the end of the time td, and on to a new title td, as I would need to submit all those deets before I move on. I suppose a flag checking whether the next row was a title td and no longer a time td would work?

Comment: Hmmm, how would I create a flag to accommodate multiple titles? If I echo $time in the $title loop, it works except for the last title. The complication with the time is that a time td might have multiple entries as well (in the same node) which might be duplicates of the following time row. So I am taking all the times, creating an array out of them, removing the duplicates, and then ordering by time.

Comment: @MetaHeavies, post the snippet of you code on http://phpfiddle.org/ for example to see it clear xD

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fix-4z5 Thanks Enissay - problem is where in the loop do I stick the DB code to take the title and the times from each block and put it into a new table...

Comment: It's the grouping that's the problem. This doesn't solve that.